Formato de fechas al crear un word
Quiero crear un word con unas tablas. En algunas de esas tablas vienen fechas.
Por ejemplo
Creo los datos:
dat <-iris[1:5,1:3]

dat$fechas <-seq(as.Date("31/03/2022", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                 by="day", length.out=5)

Creo el word donde van los datos:
library(officer)

doc <- read_docx()

doc <- doc  |>
  body_add_par("FECHAS" , style = "heading 3") |>
  body_add_par("")|>
  body_add_table(dat, style = "Table Professional")

print(doc, target = "doc.docx")

Se crea un documento con este aspecto
Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   fechas
5.1              3.5              1.4       2022-03-31
4.9              3.0              1.4       2022-04-01
4.7              3.2              1.3       2022-04-02
4.6              3.1              1.5       2022-04-03
5.0              3.6              1.4       2022-04-04

¿Hay alguna forma de que la columna fechas salga con formato día/mes/año?

Lamentablemente body_add_table() no tiene forma de ajustar el formato de alguna columna por lo que la única manera sería darle formato antes:
dat$fechas <- format(dat$fechas, "%d/%m/%Y")

Otra alternativa es usar el paquete flextable que tiene mucho mejor control y opciones sobre las tablas:
library(officer)
library(flextable)

ft <- flextable(dat)
ft <- colformat_date(x = ft, fmt_date="%d/%m/%Y")
ft <- autofit(ft)

doc <- read_docx() |>
  body_add_par("FECHAS" , style = "heading 3") |>
  body_add_par("")|>
  body_add_flextable(ft)

print(doc, target = "doc.docx")

Resultado:

